# How about CakePHP's routes.php overhead?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes

Our software architect said that.
"maybe cake routes is heavyer than .htaccess.
so Would you use .htaccess?"

How heavy cake routes?

Does someone who measure?
how to measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's probably slower than pure .htaccess rewrite rules.

No, I don't think it matters. But most of all: it does not do the same thing. Cake routes also need to do reverse routing (that is, create a URL that fits your defined routes from an `array('controller' => ..., 'action' => ...)` array). This is an explicit feature that gives you a lot of flexibility and increased productivity during development.

You would need to extensively rewrite Cake to replace routing with .htaccess rewrites. If you're using Cake, you're automatically using its routing. If *that* is a bottleneck for you, Cake isn't for you.

Comment: +1!  As @deceze mentioned "If you're using Cake, you're automatically using its routing."  To elaborate, even the simple /controller/action/ urls that are default are wired using routes.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think it will be quite heavy.

for measuring you can get a timestamp (t0) at very first line of route file, and get another timestamp (t1) at last line.

t0 - t1 tells u the time spent.

if you found the answer, post back.